# AWS RHEL 7 AMI - Repos are disabling themselves

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, yum

We are using the official RHEL 7 AMI.

`Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-e9d5ec88`

We are enabling all of the repo's, and disabling all the subscription management

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-rhui-optional-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-rhui-supplementary-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhui-rhscl-7-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-client-config-server-7

subscription-manager config --rhsm.manage_repos=0
subscription-manager config --rhsm.auto_enable_yum_plugins=0
```

everything looks good..

```
yum repolist enabled

        "Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, search-disabled-repos",
        "repo id                                              repo name            status",
        "epel/x86_64                                          Extra Packages for E 13,756",
        "rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-rpms/x86_64                Red Hat Enterprise L  1,430",
        "rhel-7-server-rhui-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64      Red Hat Enterprise L 23,399",
        "rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms/7Server/x86_64     Red Hat Enterprise L    243",
        "rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms/7Server/x86_64               Red Hat Enterprise L 32,927",
        "rhel-7-server-rhui-supplementary-rpms/7Server/x86_64 Red Hat Enterprise L    443",
        "rhel-server-rhui-rhscl-7-rpms/7Server/x86_64         Red Hat Software Col 13,928",
        "rhui-client-config-server-7/x86_64                   Custom Repositories       4",
        "repolist: 86,130"
```

Then `sudo yum update -y` or any other yum command is ran, and the repo's are reset.

```
yum repolist enabled

        "Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, search-disabled-repos",
        "repo id                                          repo name                status",
        "epel/x86_64                                      Extra Packages for Enter 13,756",
        "rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms/7Server/x86_64 Red Hat Enterprise Linux    243",
        "rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms/7Server/x86_64           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 32,927",
        "rhui-client-config-server-7/x86_64               RHUI Client Configuratio      4",
        "repolist: 46,930"
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

An update which is applied to the 'rh-amazon-rhui-client' Red Hat-managed package on the AMI to update it from version 3.0.32 to 4.0.4 causes a one-time reset of the repository configuration.